# Measure time for a user interaction of a 3 tier java application

Tags: jakarta-ee, browser, performance-testing, servlet-3.0

We have a 3 tier web application with presentation as a servlet application, business logic is implemented in a application which runs in a ejb-container. The data is stored in a relational database.
Now we have the problem to monitor the application stack in a real time environment. We would determine **how many time each part** of the communication tooks.
Example:

- The user has opened the front end in a browser and performed an action / command.
- A request is send to the web server trough a firewall, load-balancer a.s.o.
- The request is reaching the presentation layer / the servlet on the webserver.
- The presentation performs his action and calls the business logic, for instance als a JMS-call
- The call reaching the BL, BL performs his action and have to read/manipulate data in the database by a jdbc-call.

The results have to return, all the steps.
For the server part there are many tools, which can monitor the request times, for example [glowroot][1].

- What techniques / tools can be used to monitor the communication before the request reaches the server?
- How can the different results evaluate together?